# How to get response from SOAP endpoint in java?

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am very new to SOAP, so was looking into some programs online, this is what I came up with but I get a null response, must be some silly thing, but need little help

Please take a look at my code and output below. Thanks

Code

```
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBodyElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeader;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeaderElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;

public class AtomicNumber {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      SOAPConnectionFactory sfc = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
      SOAPConnection connection = sfc.createConnection();

      MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance();
      SOAPMessage smsg = mf.createMessage();

      SOAPHeader shead = smsg.getSOAPHeader();

      SOAPBody sbody = smsg.getSOAPBody();
      shead.detachNode();
      QName bodyName = new QName("http://www.webserviceX.NET", "GetAtomicNumber", "web");
      SOAPBodyElement bodyElement = sbody.addBodyElement(bodyName);
      QName qn = new QName("ElementName");
      SOAPElement quotation = bodyElement.addChildElement(qn);

      quotation.addTextNode("iron");

      System.out.println("\n Soap Request:\n");
      smsg.writeTo(System.out);
      System.out.println();

      URL endpoint = new URL("http://www.webservicex.net/periodictable.asmx");
      SOAPMessage response = connection.call(smsg, endpoint);

    System.out.println("\n Soap Response:\n");

     System.out.println(response.getContentDescription());


    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

My Output

```
 Soap Request:

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><web:GetAtomicNumber xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET"><ElementName>sodium</ElementName></web:GetAtomicNumber></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

 Soap Response:

null
```

**Update**

This is what I am getting (Exception)

```
<faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
     <faultstring>System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Procedure or function 'GetAtomicNumber' expects parameter '@ElementName', which was not supplied.
at WebServicex.periodictable.GetAtomicNumber(String ElementName)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</faultstring>
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace you are seeing? :)

Comment: @ChathurangaChandrasekara: Please check my update, I think I understood what you meant

Comment: @Ricky It gets much easier than this.  Please see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is auto-generate Java code for this web service.  The WSDL is here: http://www.webservicex.net/periodictable.asmx?wsdl

In Java, the tool to auto-generate the code is `wsimport`.  You'll want to use something like this:

```
wsimport http://www.webservicex.net/periodictable.asmx?wsdl -p com.company.whateveruwant -Xnocompile -d . -keep
```

This will put the code you want in the specified package (here `com.company.whateveruwant`).

From there, all you have to do is simply invoke the SOAP method like a normal Java library:

```
PeriodictableSoap soap = new Periodictable().getPeriodictableSoap();
System.out.println(soap.getAtomicNumber("Iron"));
```

This prints out:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <AtomicNumber>26</AtomicNumber>
    <ElementName>Iron</ElementName>
    <Symbol>Fe</Symbol>
    <AtomicWeight>55.847</AtomicWeight>
    <BoilingPoint>3300</BoilingPoint>
    <IonisationPotential>7.9</IonisationPotential>
    <EletroNegativity>1.6400000000000001</EletroNegativity>
    <AtomicRadius>1.17</AtomicRadius>
    <MeltingPoint>1808</MeltingPoint>
    <Density>7874</Density>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
   QName qn = new QName("http://www.webserviceX.NET","ElementName","web");
```

EDIT: Also, as others have suggested - you will be better off using generated client code here - Axis, JAX-WS etc are all options.

The correct code should be as below.

```
  QName bodyName = new QName("http://www.webserviceX.NET", "GetAtomicNumber");
  SOAPBodyElement bodyElement = sbody.addBodyElement(bodyName);
  QName qn = new QName("ElementName");
```

Comment: Tried still null. Please check my 1st screenshot, If I send request something like that I get the desired response

Comment: Exactly - you are missing the "web" namespace in the ElementName tag. I edited my answer shortly after I posted it - did u try the latest version I posted?

Comment: How does your SOAP request look after the change? Does it have the web namespace now?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use bare SOAP classes? How about [generating JAX-WS artifacts](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-wsimport-tool-example/) to get rid of all this boilerplate?

More info (incorporating ANT) [here](http://jxs.me/2010/05/11/java-web-service-client-wsdl/).

Comment: I need to know what is it that I is going wrong in this program

Answer (score 0):

With cxf-codegen-plugin maven plugin you can create a client of the soap service quickly by adding these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

and adding this build section:

org.apache.cxf
                cxf-codegen-plugin
                2.1.2
                
                    
                        generate-sources
                        generate-sources
                        
                            wsdl2java
                        
                        
                            ${basedir}/target/generated-sources/cxf
                            
                                
                                    ${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdlfile.wsdl
                                    
                                        -client
                                        -wsdlLocation
                                        
                                        -p
                                        com.package.for.generated.classes

then inside ${basedir}/target/generated-sources/cxf you will have classes required to call the web service and an example of how to do it.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

@Ricky, this is the correct code.

```
SOAPBody body = message.getSOAPBody();
QName bodyName = new QName("http://www.webserviceX.NET", "GetAtomicNumber");
SOAPBodyElement bodyElement = body.addBodyElement(bodyName);
SOAPElement symbol = bodyElement.addChildElement("MyMetal");
symbol.addTextNode("iron");
SOAPConnection connection = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance().createConnection();
SOAPMessage response = connection.call(message, endpoint);
connection.close();
message.writeTo(System.out);
System.out.println();
response.writeTo(System.out);
System.out.println();
```